# Sentry error logs not working in laravel mix

Tags: laravel, sentry, laravel-mix

i am using sentry fot frontend  error detection in my laravel project.I am using laravel-mix for bundling js and csss file.So i included sentry init function in my app.js file.but error inside imported js file not throw in sentry.here is my code

```
require('bootstrap');
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
import "./modules/custom";

Sentry.init({ dsn:'https://senry link here' });
```